# How to navigate python3, pip3, venv and install packages to the correct place for the correct project

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pip

I am thoroughly confused by venv, Python3, Pip3, and installing a module into my venv project.

I would like to get one non-builtin module installed to this one project and I will go from there, but trying to figure out which place I should be looking to get which Pip3 installing packages requires clarification at this point.

These are the multitude of files in various paths that I'm not sure how to navigate, or which should be navigated to.

And I can only imagine how this problem compounds after you have more than one project.

```
viru@factoBox:~/Projects/QuestInUTF8$ which python3 && which pip3 && source ../QuestInUTF8/usr/bin/activate
/usr/bin/python3
/home/viru/.local/bin/pip3
(QuestInUTF8) viru@factoBox:~/Projects/QuestInUTF8$ which python3 && which pip3
/usr/bin/python3
/home/viru/.local/bin/pip3
```

This is to show that... regardless of the env, it seems to draw from the same paths. Is that normal?

```
(QuestInUTF8) viru@factoBox:~/Projects/QuestInUTF8$ ls usr/bin/
activate  activate.csh  activate.fish  easy_install  easy_install-3.6  pip  pip3  pip3.6  python  python3  python3.6

(QuestInUTF8) viru@factoBox:~/Projects/QuestInUTF8$ ls lib/python3.6/site-packages/
easy_install.py  pip  pip-9.0.1.dist-info  pkg_resources  pkg_resources-0.0.0.dist-info  __pycache__  setuptools  setuptools-39.0.1.dist-info

(QuestInUTF8) viru@factoBox:~/Projects/QuestInUTF8$ ls ~/.local/bin && ls ~/.local/lib
easy_install      pelican             pelican-themes  pip3.6           __pycache__   rst2html5.py  rst2man.py             rst2pseudoxml.py  rst2xml.py      virtualenv
easy_install-3.6  pelican-import      pip             pipenv           pygmentize    rst2html.py   rst2odt_prepstyles.py  rst2s5.py         rstpep2html.py  virtualenv-clone
markdown_py       pelican-quickstart  pip3            pipenv-resolver  rst2html4.py  rst2latex.py  rst2odt.py             rst2xetex.py      unidecode
python3.6
```

Venv just seems to create a lot of different files everywhere with no sensible determination in a change in what is used for what, which I thought was the purpose. To me, it appears that the venv is only adding "(ProjectName)" to the prompt.

I worry that I am missing something pivotal about how venv should be functioning before I progress.

```
(QuestInUTF8) viru@factoBox:~/Projects/QuestInUTF8$ pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/viru/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (19.0.3)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /home/viru/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (40.8.0)

(QuestInUTF8) viru@factoBox:~/Projects/QuestInUTF8$ pip3 install simpleaudio
Collecting simpleaudio
Installing collected packages: simpleaudio
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

From the simpleaudio [website](https://simpleaudio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installation-ref):

> "Also, in some cases you may need to manually add pip’s location to
>   the ‘path’ environment variable."

Is this what I should do next, and where/how should I do that?